# Turing machine notation question.

Tags: notation, turing-machines

I'm a bit confused on some of the notation being used for turing machines in one of our exercises in class.

The question gives us a string α ϵ {0,1}* and the function int(α) that changes a binary number to its base 10 form. (example, int(00010) = int(10) = 2)

Now comes the tricky part:
Define the language L ⊆ {0, 1, #}* by:
L = {α#β | α, β ∈ {0, 1}* and **|β| ≥ int(α) ≥ 1 and β_{int(α)} = 1**}.

This bolded section is confusing me, and it seems like there are different variations of T.M. notation as well...

Could someone give me a rough approximation of what this might mean?

Extra: 
Examples for language L:
 $\#111 \notin L$
$00010\#11100 \in L$
$00011\#010111 \notin L$
$00011\#11 \notin L$
$1\#\#1 \notin L$

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It this exercise in a book?  If so, what book and what page? My guess is that $\beta\_n$ means the $n$th symbol in the string $\beta$.

Comment: This is right off of a page the prof wrote up unfortunately..